# Would you say "not of been" or "not have been"

Tags: terminology

I have just wrote out a sentence that ended, "this would not *of* been possible." but the more I look at it, the more it looks wrong.

Would the correct saying be, "this would not *have* been possible."?

Or do both apply?

Comment: The auxiliary verb is *have*. *Of* is not even a verb at all. "Have been" is always "have been". There is no such thing as "of been".

Comment: No. of is wrong, but used in some places in daily speech

Comment: @mplungjan what's used in speech is the contraction "'ve", not the preposition "of".

Comment: I know. I did not see it had be exacerbated by the not in between